# How to i retrieve the values of a field, in the screen auto generated by the PARAMETERS statement?

Tags: parameters, event-handling, abap

```
PARAMETERS: p_1 TYPE i, p_2 TYPE i.
```

In the initial screen, i see therefore 2 text boxes, one for each parameter.

If i fill in one of them, but don't press enter, and then I call F4 help on the second one, i'd like to be able to check for the value of the first one in the `AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON VALUE REQUEST FOR p_2`.

I need this in order for my second parameter suggestions to make sense. I need to get only those values p_2 for which the row in my table contains (in the proper place) the p_1 value. If i don't do this, most of the time the user will have have no results when entering the 2 parameters.

I heard that there is a function that gets for me the value of the parameters on the screen, but i don't really know how to tell google what i want :P
If you know other ways, it's all good, i just want the values on the screen

Thx, you guys rule!

Comment: Good question, i've come accross this limitation too, you can't even access the previous p_2 value (if it had any). Too bad i don't know the answer (i have a clue but i never dig about it) let's see if some ABAP adept can answer this. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FM DYNP_VALUES_READ will do what you want.